# Behind the scenes of "Windows is searching for a solution ..."?

Tags: windows, runtime-error

So when a program dies rather ungracefully, modern versions of Windows put up a dialog that reads:

> Windows is searching for a solution to the problem

It clocks for a little while, then doesn't find anything. Well, I've never had it tell me it's found a solution.

The question is, what exactly is going on when this dialog is being shown? What are possible things it can show as "solutions"? Is there a way my application can tap into it?

Obviously, if I know enough about what could go wrong, I should handle it in the app, so I'm left wondering what this actually does.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is capturing a stack trace of the failed program and sending it off to Microsoft.  The data it collects is stuffed into an enormous database for vendors to research; if this is your program, you can sign up [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=84169).  If the vendor submits a patch, Windows will notify you.

You can tap into it, either by [customizing the info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), triggering reports for (soon to be) fatal errors, and much more.